# For loop in Python3, using variable[i-1]

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I need help, everytime i use a for loop in Python3 like:

```
for i in range(len(sequence)):
```

and i write:

```
sequence[i-1]
```

in the first loop it gets the last number of the sequence, how can i change that?

example:

```
a=(10,15,20)
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i]=a[i-1]+a[i]
```

i want to get

> [ 10,25,35]

but i get

> [45,25,35]

Comment: What do you want it to get in the first iteration?

Comment: the generic way to achieve this could be to start with index=0, add with `next(iter)` and stop when StopIterationError occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to answer the question in the title: `a[-1]` will always give you the last element and you can't change that.

but you can still make your code work:

first of all there are a couple problems in your code besides the one you asked about:

- your current code can't even run, you can't reassign a value in a tuple
- even if `a` was a list it wouldn't give you the desired output, since you are changing the values as you go, so everything past the first pair will be wrong

i assume what you want to do is sum all pairs and replace each number with the pair, except for the first number which should be the same

you can do that in several ways but here's a pretty simple to understand way:

```
a = [10,15,20]
b = [a[0]]
for i in range(1,len(a)):
    b.append(a[i] + a[i-1])
```

and now `b` looks like this: `[10, 25, 35]`

or if you want to do it without an additional list you can go in reverse:

```
a = [10,15,20]
for i in range(len(a),1,-1):
     a[i] = a[i] + a[i-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `range(1,len(a))` because if you use `range(len(a))` then iteration will start with 0 which will cause `a[i-1]` to be `a[-1]` which will result last value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a=[10,15,20]
b=[a[i]+a[i-1] for i in range(1,len(a))]
b.insert(0,a[0])
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[10, 25, 35]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first iteration of the for loop, i=0. i-1 would equal -1.
a[-1] finds the LAST item of "a" so therefore 10+35 is 45.

To fix, use range(1,len(a)) as shown to ignore the first item:

```
a=[10,15,20]
for i in range(1, len(a)):
    a[i]=b[i-1]+a[i]
```

This then creates another issue - the second value of a is now 25, not 15. So therefore the last output is 45, not 35 as intended.

To fix this, create a duplicate of "a"

```
a=[10,15,20]
b=[10,15,20]
for i in range(1, len(a)):
    a[i]=b[i-1]+a[i]
```

Therefore if you were to output a, you would get

```
[10,25,35]
```

as desired.

Answer (score 0):

One could also try to remove indexes at all (except the first one):

```
a = (10, 15, 20)
result = [a[0]] + [(x + y) for x, y in zip(a[:-1], a[1:])]
assert result == [10, 25, 35]
```